# Linux: How to automatically detect display and set up default editor accordingly

Tags: linux, vim, alias

I am relatively new to linux.  I am connecting to a remote linux machine sometimes via telnet and sometimes via NX client for windows.  When I connect via telent I would like the default editor to be vim, and when I connect via NX I would like the default editor to be gvim.  Is there a way to automatically detect which connection I am using when the alias file is sourced?  Right now I have the following in my alias file:

```
alias usevim 'setenv CSCOPE_EDITOR vim; setenv EDITOR vim'
alias usegvim 'setenv CSCOPE_EDITOR gvim; setenv EDITOR gvim'
echo 'using vim'
usevim
```

This sets the default editor to vim.  When I connect via NX, the first thing I will do is type 'usegvim'.  I would like to not have to do this every time!  Is there a way to detect whether a display is present or not?

Thanks!

UPDATE:  if($?DISPLAY) doesn't work because my .cshrci file has a line with "setenv DISPLAY ..."

UPDATE:  I am now using cygwin to ssh into the remote box and using Cygwin XWin Server to display my gui apps.  Now I don't need to worry about which editor to use because gvim is always available.  I will probably ditch NX client because everything I need can now be launched directly from the command line and gui apps work just like native windows apps.

Comment: Why on earth would you use `telnet` in this day and age? The only sane choice is [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). In fact, enabling a telnet server on these days is (quite rightly) a fair amount of effort.

Comment: as an addition to the comment before: telnet is sending everything unencrypted in plain text, wheras ssh uses very secure encryption by default. everyone on the way from one machine to the other could read everything you do!

Comment: Good point.  I am now using ssh.

Answer (score 2):

The `DISPLAY` variable is set when an X11 (graphical) display is in use. When using telnet, `DISPLAY` will not be defined.

It looks like you're using a *csh* derivative which I don't really know, but I think you could add something like this to your .tcshrc file:

```
if ($DISPLAY) then
    setenv CSCOPE_EDITOR gvim
    setenv EDITOR gvim
else
    setenv CSCOPE_EDITOR vim
    setenv EDITOR vim
endif
```

Comment: Revised my answer to fix the inverted logic. New code will use gvim when DISPLAY is set.

Answer (score 1):

Just always use "gvim" or "vim -g".  It will complain if the X display isn't available, but it will still start the console version.